# atom C++ stringについて

Tags: c++, vscode, atom-editor

Atom（vscodeでも）C++のソースコード（以下に示す）を作成し、実行したときstring系が使えないのですがどなたか改善策を教えてはいただけないでしょうか？
コンパイラーはMinGwです。

実行結果[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

ソースコード

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(void){
  string first_name;
  string last_name;
  string full_name;
  first_name="Steve";
  last_name="O";
  full_name=first_name+last_name;
  cout<<full_name<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

正常動作をするサンプルコードを以下に掲載しておきます。

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
  int a, b;

  cin>> a >> b;

  if ( a < b ){
    cout << "a < b" << endl;
  }
  else if ( a > b ){
    cout << "a > b" << endl;
  }
  else{
    cout << "a == b" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 必要な情報があれば教えていただければお伝えします。

Comment: 「実行」は実際には何をしましたか？手順を教えて下さい。

Comment: atomでしたら追加packageのlinter-gccを使い、f5を押して実行をしました。

Comment: 数値計算とcout<<"文字列"では問題なく動作します。

Comment: linter-gcc、使った事ないので分かりませんが、linter という言葉の通りであれば実行する物ではなく書式のエラーをチェックする物な気がしますが如何でしょうか。

Comment: すみません。初心者なもので以下のサイトを見様見真似で設定をしました。http://gabekore.org/windows-atom-clang

Comment: つまりは仮想的にしか実行が行われていないということなんですか？とりあえずコマンドプロンプト経由でこのファイルを実行してみます。アドバイスありがとうございます。

Comment: だと思います。記事の中に書いてある script を入れてみてはどうでしょうか。 https://atom.io/packages/script

Comment: 何度もすみません調べ直すと実際に実行を行っていたのはgpp-compilerというpackageでした

Comment: なるほど。https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler
ここを見る限り、パスが通っていれば良いようなのでコマンドプロンプトから実行できるか確認してみて下さい。

Comment: pathは通ってます。数値計算と標準入出力ストリームは問題なく使えます。一応、コマンドプロんプとから試してみます。

Comment: ファイルの拡張子が .c だったりしないでしょうか？C++ であれば .cpp や .cxx でなければなりません。

Comment: そこは大丈夫でした。.cpp形式でした。

Comment: ちなみに string を使わないコードだと動くという事でしょうか？メイン部分が `int main() { string s = "foo"; cout << s << "\n\n"; }` でも動きませんか？

Comment: その場合以下の2つのエラーが出ました。'string' was not declared in this scope.とsuggested alternatives:尚ソースコードは#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main() {
   string s = "foo"; cout << s << "\n\n";
  }
でエラーの場所はstringの場所を指していました

Comment: あ、↑では略して書きましたが `using namespace std;` は必要です。

Comment: すみません。書き加えるとエラーがなくなりましたが、初期の質問と実行結果は同じ形になりました

Comment: つまり何も表示されなくなったという事でしょうか？

Comment: そうですね何も表示されません。

Comment: おそらくですが、gpp-compiler に問題がある気がします。記事にあった scripts を試されてはどうでしょうか？(質問のコード、整形させてもらいました)

Comment: 動作しないパターンだけでなく「問題なく動作」するパターンも提示してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。現在scriptに変更中です。

Comment: 挙げられたコードはどちらも手元の環境では正常に動作します。ただしコードは当初、全角空白で区切られていたなど実際にコンパイルしたコードとは異なるようです。また挙げられていない部分、インストールしたバージョンやコンパイル方法、実行方法などが影響しているかもしれません。Windows環境で無難にプログラミングを行うのであれば、まずはVisual Studioをお勧めしたいところですが…atomやvscode、MinGWにこだわりがおありでしょうか？

Comment: 出来れば動作が軽いものしようしたいです。

Answer (score 2):

すみません。
解決しました。お恥ずかしながら、mingwのインストールが64bitと32bitが間違っていました。
導入し直しで治りました。
本当にすいません。
回答してくださったお二方ありがとうございます。